# MYSQL query issue on the merge

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a MYSQL Query as below:

```
SELECT COUNT(od.id)+IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(rmrs.id)
FROM ic_dd_results rmrs
WHERE rmd.horse_id = od.horse_mraid AND rmrs.finish_pos = '1'),0) as count_win
FROM ic_dd_old_data od
WHERE od.horse_mraid = '123123' AND od.pl='1'
```

The Query will return correct data when the first query count_win is matching `finish_pos =1`, but when the second query does not have the data for `pl='1'`, it will ignore the first query. 
I want the total of query result return by combine both 1st and 2nd.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please provide table structure, data sample and the desired output. Also, make sure to clarify your question.

Comment: Your query is invalid (according to the SQL stadard). You select `ic_dd_old_data` records, each along with an `ic_dd_results` count. Then you count all those rows and to this count you add *what*? Remember that you generated multiple `ic_dd_results` counts, but suddenly you treat this as if it were one single value that you could add to the row count. MySQL lets this slip and arbitrarily picks one `ic_dd_results` count for you. (You could make this explicit by writing `ANY_VALUE(IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(rmrs.id) ...)`.) Think about what you really want to add or count.

Comment: Sorry guy as I am still new to this portal and I will try to make the question clear with all the support notes so it is easy for others to help.

Comment: Appreciate everyone for help and will take note in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are merely looking for

```
select 
  (select count(*) from ic_dd_old_data where horse_mraid = 123123 and pl = 1) +  
  (select count(*) from ic_dd_results where horse_id = 123123 and finish_pos = 1);
```

Comment: I was be thinking that also.

Comment: Maybe both will work by split out the count statement. The full code is as below: 
I skipped the inner join part as just confuse with the query all in 1.

<code>SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN od.pl='1' THEN od.id END)+IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(rmrs.id)
FROM ic_dd_results rmrs
INNER JOIN ic_dd_race rmr ON rmr.track_id = rmrs.track_id AND rmr.post_id = rmrs.post_id
INNER JOIN ic_dd_declaration rmd ON rmd.race_id = rmr.race_id AND rmd.horse_no = rmrs.horse_no 
WHERE rmd.horse_id = od.horse_mraid AND rmrs.finish_pos = '1'),0) as count_win
FROM ic_dd_old_data od
WHERE od.horse_mraid = '".$horse_mra."'

Comment: This is analogous to Yogesh Sharma's answer. Invalid SQL, which - provided MySQL is not in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode - MySQL permits though, by arbitrarily picking one count_win from all those equal count_win in the intermediate result. I know that your query works, but you should be aware what this query really does and you should learn to write the proper query instead. `COUNT` always returns a number by the way, never null; so `IFNULL` is superfluous in your query.

Comment: Hi @ThorstenKettner thank you for your detail explain. So you mean that in terms of performance wise it will better to use below?

`select 
  (select count(*) from ic_dd_old_data where horse_mraid = 123123 and pl = 1) +  
  (select count(*) from ic_dd_results where horse_id = 123123 and finish_pos = 1);`

Comment: Yes, that query is standard-compliant and should be as fast as possible. After all it's just a sum from one table plus a sum from another that you want. No need to join. When you want this for more than one horse ID though, with one row per ID, then you'd join. But you'd join subqueries...

Comment: ... (i.e. `select horse_id, coalesce(o.cnt,0) + coalesce(r.cnt,0) as total from (select horse_mraid as horse_id, count(*) as cnt from ic_dd_old_data where pl = 1 group by horse_mraid) o full outer join (select horse_id, count(*) as cnt from ic_dd_results where finish_pos = 1 group by horse_id) using (horse_id) r` for a DBMS featuring full outer joins).

Comment: Thank you so much @ThorstenKettner, will learn it in more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also do that via conditional *aggregation* instead of filtering `pl=1` in `where` clause

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN od.pl='1' THEN od.id END) + 
       IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(rmrs.id)
               FROM ic_dd_results rmrs
               WHERE rmd.horse_id = od.horse_mraid AND 
               rmrs.finish_pos = '1'),0) as count_win
FROM ic_dd_old_data od
WHERE od.horse_mraid = '123123'
```

Comment: thank you for your quick code and it is working perfectly! Appreciate so much.

Comment: This is not a good query, though. It only works, because all rows in the intermediate result have the same count_win, of which one gets arbitrarily picked.